# Conditional type inference

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements

Based on the variable `FLAG` with the value `true`, I would like the type of the variable `result` to be explicit inferred, because in example below there is no doubt that the result should be type of `string`.

```
const FLAG = true;

let result;
if (FLAG) {
  result = "";
} else {
  result = 1;
}

// here result is an union of type `string | number`, but I wish it to be type of `string`
```

I have no ideas how to achieve expected result.

I was trying with conditional types, but without any effects.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of typescript. But why are you not using like `let result = 1; if (FLAG) {
  result = "";
}`

Comment: By default, when the application is running, the flag type will be `true` | `false`. Based on the value of the flag, the appropriate result will be returned. However, I want to be able to set the flag manually during development, so that the typescript tells me that the result is of the type that was inferred from the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your example, you want Typescript to interpret the `else` block to be unreachable since the `FLAG` is a constant that is always going to be true making the type of `result` a `string`. However, doing some reading I found that Typescript doesn't do reachability based on types because it prevents from writing defensive code ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47405#issuecomment-1011251910))

```
function f(s: string) {
  if (typeof s !== "string") {
    throw new Error("Bad JS caller go away");
    // ^ "unreachable"
  }
  // etc
}
```